# Unexpected result from numpy random.shuffle

Tags: python, numpy

I am using `numpy.random.shuffle` to scramble an binary array (code below) but the output does not appear very random. I would expect a random assortment of dots but the resulting array appears to be a semi-regular pattern of dashes. What is going on here?

```
img = PIL.Image.open(image_path)         
array = numpy.array(img)
# threshold image etc
outim=PIL.Image.fromarray(array)
outim.show()  # generates left image (below)

numpy.random.shuffle(array)
outim=PIL.Image.fromarray(array)
outim.show()   # generates right image (below)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have shuffled the rows but not the columns. [`numpy.random.shuffle`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) reorders its input along the first dimension only.

To shuffle the entire thing, try

```
shape = array.shape
array = array.flatten()
numpy.random.shuffle(array)
array = array.reshape(shape)
```

Comment: Don't you need to reshape it after shuffling?

Comment: Hmm.. thanks or he suggestion but `.flatten()` doesn't seem to shuffle anything

Comment: @ElConfuso `flatten` doesn't shuffle anything, it just reshapes the array into a 1-dimensional array.